# What to do after split String?

Tags: python, split

I have an IP address that I need to split in order to know the location of the device.

```
s = "11.19.27.55"

ip = [item[::-1] for item in s[::-1].split('.', 1)][::-1]

print(ip)
```

Result:

```
['11.19.27', '55']
```

How can I now compare to certain parts of this result?
The first part I need for location second part for knowing which device it is.

Comment: you do not need to use ::-1 every time, it is just a step, use  `[item for item in s.split('.')]`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself:

print(ip[0])  for the first part

print(ip[1]) for the second part